# $f$ is Differentiable on all of ${\Bbb R}$ and $\lim_{\ x\to\infty} f^{'}(x) = 0.$ Show $\lim_{\ x\to\infty} (f(x+1)-f(x))=0.$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> Suppose $f$ is Differentiable on all of ${\Bbb R}$ and that $\lim_{\ x\to\infty} f^{'}(x) = 0.$ Show that $\lim_{\ x\to\infty} (f(x+1)-f(x))=0.$

I tried to prove by this logic,

$\lim_{\ x\to\infty} f^{'}(x) = 0 \Rightarrow \lim_{\ x\to\infty}\left(\lim_{\ h\to\ 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right) = 0 \Rightarrow f^{'}(x) = 0, \forall x\in{\Bbb R}$.

Thus, $f$ is constant which implies $f(x+1)=f(x) \Rightarrow \lim_{\ x\to\infty} (f(x+1)-f(x))=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your conclusion that $f$ is constant is wrong (A function that satifies your conditions is $f(x) = \ln(x)$).

What you need is the mean-value theorem. Suppose $\lim_{x\to \infty} f'(x) = 0$, then for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is $M > 0$ such that
$$
z > M \Rightarrow |f'(z)| < \epsilon
$$
Now, if $x > M$, then there is some $z\in (x,x+1)$ so that
$$
|f(x+1) - f(x)| = |f'(z)| < \epsilon
$$
Hence
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x+1) - f(x) = 0
$$